# Angular 2 - Redirct a user to homepage if they try to access a logged in page. (I need it not to hit the components constructor)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Angular 2 - Redirct a user to homepage if they try to access a logged in page. (I need it not to hit the components constructor)

I'm using typescript and angular2.

Currently only works if I have no calls to services in a components constructor.

**Currently I'm using doing this (But it keeps hitting the internal components constructor still and causing errors):**

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes: any;
  private parentRouter: Router;

  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.publicRoutes = { 
      '/Home': true 
    };
  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {     
      console.log("here");
      this.parentRouter.navigate(['/Home']);
      return super.activate(instruction); 
  }
}
```

It currently only works if an internal page doesn't have anything in its constructor.

Comment: `this.parentRouter.navigate(['/Home']);`

Comment: I have tried that. Still hits the internal components constructor. It needs to redirect to home before hitting the internal components constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is @CanActivate directive in front of protected component.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html

```
@CanActivate(() => checkAuth())
export class ProtectedCMP {}
```

Consider this Plunker (protected.component.ts )

https://plnkr.co/edit/sGzQIFsLJaFHsjGT1MpP?p=preview

Comment: Do you mean in front of a components constructor?

Comment: So like this:

@CanActivate(false); which would then redirect to home page like in my above code?

Comment: @CanActivate(() => false) for example, it will not redirect you must write additional code for that.

Comment: I get an error called: Declaration expect . Do I need to import CanActivate?

Comment: Sure, from "angular2/router" Check my Plunker in answer.

Comment: I got it almost working now. I did this: @CanActivate(() => false) and it doesnt go into the component which is good. However it doesnt redirect to homepage?

Comment: Check my Plunker again, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now. Problem is, I have a lot of internal pages. I dont want to add this same code to all the components. Isnt there an interceptor way to catch it so I dont need to do this before every component?

Comment: You can do something like this, inside your activate() function, catch current url with: let url = this.parentRouter.lastNavigationAttempt; , than somehow make array of protected url's, and manually resolve it...

Comment: I've tried that. Problem is, when the activate part of the code is hit it still hits the components constructor

Comment: @CanActivate() is kind od standard for that

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. None of these are solutions for what I need

Comment: @AngularM Angular2 does not support a dynamic route interceptor at this time. I would recommend submitting a feature request with the Angular 2 team. There is a `subscribe` method on the router, which will be triggered with each navigation, and you can trigger redirections using this as well, but the initial route navigated to will still constuct and display for an instant before redirecting. The only supported way to do what you are asking for at this time is the `CanActivate` decorator in the answer above.

Comment: @AngularM as for constructors, my recommendation is to try not to use constructors at all and instead use the `ngOnInit` and/or `routerOnActivate` methods for setting initial state. There are some caveats to using the constructor and this can bite you in the future.

Comment: I improved my answer, it is my last resort to help you. In checkAuth function, i hard coded stuff, probably you will resolve that with http call...

Comment: For routerOnActivate where do I import it from? I tried importing it from router but it errors in my compiler

Comment: ngOnInit works fine. I moved that to the components neccessary. cheers guys

Comment: @SnareChops if you make an answer I can aware you the bounty

Comment: @AngularM It doesn't feel right to accept the bounty as I didn't actually answer the question, just suggested a minor change and you were satisfied with that. The bounty should probably go to Vlado or another actual answer that comes in.